# Printing regex matches from string.replace using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've a list of banned words, and when the user tries to submit text with one of them I want to have a small warning that tells them the banned words they have used. Right now it works, but for some reason only tells them the last banned word they used.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Syntax Highlighting</title>
<!-- Main Quill library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style> #editor-container { height: 130px; } 
    #banned-words { color: #660000; font-weight: bold; }</style>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="form-container" class="container">
        <form name="badwords" method="post" action="" >
            <div class="row form-group">
              <label for="about">Appraisal Info</label>
              <input name="about" type="hidden">
              <div id="banned-words"> </div>
              <div id="editor-container">

            </div>
            </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="formSub" type="submit">Submit!</button>
          </div>    
        </form>
    </div>
 </body>

<script src="parch.js"></script>
 <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script type="text/javascript">
var div = document.getElementById('formSub'); 

function replaceWords(event) {
    //Prevent form submission to server 
    event.preventDefault();
    var commentContent = quill.getText();
    var badWords = ["green","yellow","blue"];
        console.log(commentContent)
        commentContent =censore(commentContent, badWords);
}   

function censore(string, filters) {
    console.log('in')
    // "i" is to ignore case and "g" for global "|" for OR match
    var regex = new RegExp(filters.join("|"), "gi");
   return string.replace(regex, function (match) {
        var clean = match;
        console.log(clean);
        document.getElementById('banned-words').innerHTML = "Your description contained some sensitive words, please review the usage of the following words: " + match;
});
}
div.addEventListener('click',replaceWords); 
</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: You just need to append the notification, probably. `document.getElementById('banned-words').innerHTML =` = > `document.getElementById('banned-words').innerHTML +=`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much! That let me fix it.

Comment: Fyi, it's faster to have a global or const regex pre-made instead of constructing the same one each time the handler is called.

Comment: @sln I'll have to try and rewrite it to incorporate that. Thank you for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

In this method

```
 return string.replace(regex, function (match) {
    var clean = match;
    console.log(clean);
    document.getElementById('banned-words').innerHTML = "Your description contained some sensitive words, please review the usage of the following words: " + match;
 }
```

You are setting the innerHTML each time this method is invoked. The `replace` method on string calls the matcher function for every match. So it will only show the last matched word. In other words, every time it finds a match, it is replacing the whole thing entirely.

Ideally you would keep a list of matches then at the end of the censor function add the warning and the whole list.